# Google Cloud Platform IP ranges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, cloud

I am trying to setup firewall outbound rules to allow access to google cloud platform. What is the IP range of google cloud platform?
Thanks!

Comment: What's your requierement? What do you want to protect? And from what? where?

Comment: Clarify what your objective is. Google Cloud does not publish a list for all of Google Cloud just certain resources. There are much better ways of providing access to Google Cloud services than using firewall rules (for which you will run out of trying your method).

Answer (score 3):

This is related to Compute engine? If so, Compute Engine IP ranges can be found on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range)

> Google Cloud publishes a JSON-formatted list of customer-usable global
> and regional external IP address ranges in cloud.json.

or you can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-ip-address)

> Learn how to locate external and internal IP addresses for your
> instance.

Yo can see additional information about IP addresses [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/ip-addresses) as well.